# Terraform import fails due to erroneous region although defined in the provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am using the following tf configuration:

```
variable "aws_profile" {
  description = "The AWS profile to use for this account"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "${var.aws_profile}"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2"
  region  = "us-west-2"
  alias   = "us_west_2"
  profile = "profile-us-west-2"
}
```

where

```
cat ~/.aws/credentials

[profile-us-west-2]
region=us-west-2
aws_access_key_id = ΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧ
aws_secret_access_key =  ΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧΧ
```

and trying to `import` an existing `S3` bucket

to the tf resource below

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_tf_bucket" {
  provider = "aws.us_west_2"
  bucket   = "my_tf_bucket"
```

with the following command:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_tf_bucket existing_bucket_name
```

which fails as follows:

```
 Error importing AWS S3 bucket policy: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-west-2'
    status code: 400, request id: 64242424244D21946, host id: bddw422424
```

Why isn't the `provider` alias working?

Comment: Do you check if the env vars AWS_REGION or AWS_DEFAULT_REGION are set or not ?

Comment: they are not set, I checked

Comment: I think the problem comes from either the bucket name ( in this case try to change this with unique one ) or from the fact that you import the same object multiple time and it's already exist in your state file ( try to change the backend or move your state file to be sure.) 
N.B: sometimes the error messages in terraform does not really reflect the problem in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that (for some reason), `terraform` requires to explicitly pass the `provider` value when importing

```
terraform import --provider=aws.us_west_2 aws_s3_bucket.my_tf_bucket existing_bucket_name
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. It does seem like an issue with older TF versions before 12.26. The documentation says that this option is deprecated and Config file would be used. However, if you saw this in recent versions as well, then the issue still remains. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17139 .... However, good that ur issue is fixed...